# Remove duplicate adjacent of specific string from list

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates

I want to remove the duplicate adjacent of specific string from list. Suppose that I have a list as below:

```
list_ex = ['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'big', 'conference', ',', 'I', 'presented', 'myself', 'there', '.', 'After', 'the', '<word>conference</word>', '<word>conference</word>', ',', 'I', 'took', 'a', 'taxi', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', '<word>hotel</word>', '<word>hotel</word>', '.', 'Tomorrow', 'I', 'will', 'go', 'to', '<word>conference</word>', 'again', '.']
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
for item in list_ex:
    if item.startswith('<word>'):
        if item in new_list_ex and (item == list_ex[list_ex.index(item)+1]):
            continue
    new_list_ex.append(item)
```

My output of **new_list_ex**:

```
['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'big', 'conference', ',', 'I', 'presented', 'myself', 'there', '.', 'After', 'the', '<word>conference</word>', ',', 'I', 'took', 'a', 'taxi', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', '<word>hotel</word>', '.', 'Tomorrow', 'I', 'will', 'go', 'to', 'again', '.']
```

Desired output:

```
['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'big', 'conference', ',', 'I', 'presented', 'myself', 'there', '.', 'After', 'the', '<word>conference</word>', ',', 'I', 'took', 'a', 'taxi', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', '<word>hotel</word>', '.', 'Tomorrow', 'I', 'will', 'go', 'to', '<word>conference</word>', 'again', '.']
```

I feel like my **list_ex[list_ex.index(item)+1]** to detect the adjacent element did not work properly. How can I adjust to get the desired output?

Please note that order in this list is important.

Comment: What you want to do is skip the word if it's flagged (startswith(<word>)) and is equal to the LAST element of new_list_ex; try `if item.startswith('<word>') and (item == new_list_ex[-1]):`

Comment: @Mohammedalmalki of course order is important.

Comment: now i understand .. you want to delete the tags and delete the duplicate word is the right ?

Comment: @Mohammedalmalki yes of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether a word flagged with `<word>` is the last item in the new_list (`new_list_ex[-1]`); if so, `continue` (skip it).
If not, just append the word to the new_list.

```
list_ex = ['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'big', 'conference', ',', 'I', 'presented', 'myself', 'there', '.', 'After', 'the', '<word>conference</word>', '<word>conference</word>', ',', 'I', 'took', 'a', 'taxi', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', '<word>hotel</word>', '<word>hotel</word>', '.', 'Tomorrow', 'I', 'will', 'go', 'to', '<word>conference</word>', 'again', '.']

new_list_ex = []
for item in list_ex:
    if item.startswith('<word>') and (item == new_list_ex[-1]):
        continue
    new_list_ex.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean this work :

```py
list_ex = ['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'big', 'conference', ',', 'I', 'presented', 'myself', 'there', '.', 'After', 'the', '<word>conference</word>', '<word>conference</word>', ',', 'I', 'took', 'a', 'taxi', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', '<word>hotel</word>', '<word>hotel</word>', '.', 'Tomorrow', 'I', 'will', 'go', 'to', '<word>conference</word>', 'again', '.']

new_list = []

for i in list_ex:
    if "<" in i and ">" in i:
        if i.split(">")[1].split("<")[0] in new_list:
            continue
        else:
            new_list.append(i.split(">")[1].split("<")[0])
    else:
        if i in new_list:
            continue
        else:
            new_list.append(i)


print(new_list)
```